# Using external variable in PHP

Tags: php, variables, post, get, isset

I have this variable inside another part of the page (another $_GET):

```
if(!isset($_GET["act"]))
{
    $prefix = $_POST["prefix"];
```

And I want to use it in another part:

```
if($_GET["act"] == "admin")
{
    $table = $prefix . "users";
```

Is there any way for me to be able to use a variable which was defined in another block? if not, how can I make it save and use it in the other block?

Comment: No, you code is illogical. You set `$prefix` only if `$_GET['act']` is **not** set. The next snippet only runs if `$_GET['act']` **is** set and equals a specific value. Both cannot be true

Comment: True, ignore my answer if Steve's right and you only set $prefix in the !isset-part of your code.

Comment: Is there any way I can overcome that problem?

Comment: Not without tearing the space time continuum... Seriously, the problem is plain logic - one value cannot both be true and false at the same time. Probably you need to explain your problem in more detail